# Issue on airflow initdb

Tags: airflow

I just start using airflow and I used the command :

`airflow initdb`

to initiate the airflow db as the setup required.
But I stumbled on the error :

`import cattr                                                                                                          File "/home/adrienb/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cattr/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>                         from .converters import Converter, GenConverter, UnstructureStrategy                                                  File "/home/adrienb/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cattr/converters.py", line 16, in <module>                      from attr import fields, resolve_types                                                                              ImportError: cannot import name 'resolve_types' from 'attr' (/home/adrienb/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr/__init__.py)`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11965) will be fixed in 1.10.13 ([PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11969))
Since you are using Python 3.8 you should use ([reference](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11965)):

```
pip install apache-airflow==1.10.12 \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.12/constraints-3.8.txt"
```

Comment: i have the same issue in 'init db', my python version is 3.7.3, what should i do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the same issue that Elad commented, in my case, adding only

```
pip install attrs==19.3.0
pip install cattrs==1.0.0
```

was enough to solve it